# Java Array issue. Throwing out of bounds exception

Tags: java, arrays

Okay, I am not sure why but i keep on getting an out of bounds exception on my 
array even though i thought it would still be within the bounds of said array.

```
public class Assignment04Arrays
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner inputArray = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many numbers do you want to enter? ");
        int numbers = inputArray.nextInt();

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int z = 0;

       int arrayTotal = numbers;
        double[] myArray;
        myArray = new double[arrayTotal];

            System.out.println(arrayTotal);

        while (x<numbers){
            Scanner arrayNumbers = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
            double arraynumber = arrayNumbers.nextDouble();

            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(arraynumber);

            /*fails here when it shouldn't*/
            myArray[x] = arraynumber;
            x++;
        }      
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it fail for any specific value of `numbers`?

Comment: There is no error with your code, how do you run it to produce this error?

Comment: I tested your code and it does not crash when I use 5 numbers and enter 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Answer (score 0):

So, testing this code out on my machine by command line, this works perfectly fine.  This code shouldn't have any issues, but it's hard to tell without knowing what your environment is and what your test inputs were.

A couple of things to try:

- Get rid of the extra Scanner in your while loop.  You're creating a scanner on each iteration and not closing any of them, and this could be causing something strange in however you're running it.
- Try running this through command line (javac Assignment04Arrays.java to compile it then java Assignment04Arrays to run it).  If this works, it's probably however you're compiling it.

If this doesn't resolve it, what were your test inputs specifically that were causing this error?